# Print in Acrobat with Color Profile and Relative or Perceptual intent

Tags: color, print-production, adobe-acrobat, color-profile, color-reproduction

I'm used to print regularly with Photoshop and custom icc color profiles, relative or perceptual intent and/or black point compensation so I'm pretty aware of that kind of settings.

I tried to follow the same approach with Acrobat, but it seems that I can't achieve the same results.

Acrobat has a different color settings window:

[image: acrobat print settings]

[image: acrobat color settings]

I can find the Color Profile but there's no question about rendering intent, and black point compensation.

I tried by picking my custom icc and disabling **treat grays as k-only grays** and **preserve black** settings, because I'm printing with desktop printer treated as RGB device.

The output result is far from the one I could get with Photoshop and correct settings, so I guess that there's something off in my print settings in Acrobat.

A different approach could have been convert everything to the destination profile before preparing the pdf but I would like to know how to do it in realtime like with Photoshop instead preparing a less portable pdf suited only for the print job with a certain printer.

Comment: Maybe Adobe Bridge is used to synchronize these settings. Do you have it enabled?

Comment: @StefanBollmann I'm not sure how Adobe Bridge can be related..